# Angular 8 : (keyup.enter) is not triggering for readonly html input

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am trying to trigger a function once the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The reason I make this input readonly is to restrict user from modifying the value in the input once the value is populated.

The value is coming from a popup which will be triggered in click attribute. The problem is the `keyup.enter` is not triggering for that input.

Below is the code:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="display.name"
  (click)="openProfile()" (keyup.enter)="submitProfile()" readonly
/>

<button (click)="submitProfile()" type="submit">
  Submit
</button>
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce it. It's working fine for me: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l43hac?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Is it a browser-specific problem?

Comment: Did you try changing `[(ngModel)]` to `[ngModel]`?

Comment: @CristianTraìna I have tried but it seems still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

You can set up the attributes:

```
[readonly]="isValuePapulated"
```

or

```
[disabled]="isValuePapulated"
```

or use only:

```
[ngModel]="display.name"
(ngModelChanged)=onModelChanged($event)
// in component:
public onModelChanged(value: any): void {
    if (isValuePapulated) {
       return;
    }

   this.display.name = value;
}
```